CCS Pricing with mandatory break clause
Suppose I have to price a 5Y EUR-GBP fix-to-fix CCS. There is a EUR CSA (ESTR flat) in place with the counterparty. Additionally, there is a mandatory break clause after N years embedded in the swap. The applicable discount rate for this is in CCY3, which is different from EUR and GBP. How would I construct the applicable discount curves in this case?
Without break it is pretty clear. ESTR discounting the EUR cashflows and (EUR CSA) Cross Currency adjusted GBP curve for the GBP flows.
Edit
Ok let's try to approach this. Suppose the following easy setup:

5Y fix-to-fix CCS GGB vs. EUR. Collateralized with EUR-CSA
Mandatory break at 2Y with USD-CSA. Hence the remaining Swap is priced with CCS adjusted basis curves with USD collateral (GBP:USD and EUR:USD)

Let's concentrate on the EUR leg only. My best guess would be to construct a blended curve such that:

Discount Factors up to 2y are exactly equal to ESTR discount factors (as any PV changes until break date are still collateralized under EUR-CSA)
Discount Factor for 3y EUR cashflow would be 2y ESTR discount factor * Forward Discount factor (2 to 3 years) from the EUR:USD collateral curve (which we already constructed).

Does that makes sense?

yes related but not really answering the question

I don't understand your definition. What does the applicable discount rate for the mandatory break is CCY3 mean? Is that the contract states that upon mandatory break each leg of the trade will be discounted and priced using a CCY3 collateral discount curve, eg. GBP:CCY3 and EUR:CCY3? Additionally if the counterparty wanted terminate earlier than mandatory would the same discount curves be used from that point, or only from the point of mandatory break?

You are right. The contract would state that the remaining swap would be priced using gbp:ccy3 and eur:ccy3 curves. But until mandatory break, there is a EUR only csa in place. So the question is how to adjust the discounting curves given these different csa agreements. Is there some kind of multi currency optionality embedded here, which needs to be taken into account?

i would value at eur csa until mandatory break and usd csa after. i would blend curves. It is very simple mathematically. I would run risk analysis to see if anything is missing gamma-wise and if there would need to be any convexity adjustements. but my instinct says it would be minor. But there is no optionality because the CSA are distinct at different times.

Yes, that would make sense. I have edited my question earlier. Maybe you can double check on the approach?
